# How to convert milliseconds to local day, date and time format in swift?

Tags: swift

I want to display the date in this format (Wed Jan 10 2018 11:20:17). How to convert milliseconds to this format in swift?I want to get the day as Wed, time as 10:30 AM or PM and the date as 10 Jan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert it in date by dividing it by 1000

```
var date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: (1477593000000 / 1000.0))
```

then use `DateFormatter`  to convert in desired format you need

Note: Not tested in XCODE

```
var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
```

Hope it is helpful to you.